# How to select all form fields within a given form element with Prototype?

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, stripes

My question might seem trivial but I can't find resources about selecting elements that are descendant of a given element.

I have a form in which I want all fields (they should be all the `input`s and `select`s that are child of the `form` tag, except buttons) to submit the form when <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key is pressed. Actually I require to call a custom Javascript method to submit the form, instead of merely submitting it the plain old way.

This because I need to raise a different Stripes `ActionBean` event depending on the button being hit (or in the case of enter key I know what event to fire a priori).

I can apply a custom CSS class to all fields (booooooooooooring) and I can select all form fields in a page with `$$('input[type!=button], select')`.

How to constrain the selection to elements that descend from a given `form` tags (which has an ID?). The selection will be used to handle the `keyup` event

Comment: Submitting the form on pressing enter is default browser behavior, you don't need a script for that?

Comment: "Actually I require to call a custom Javascript method to submit the form.". - My forms raise a different Stripes ActionBean event depending on the button being hit and there is **no** default one. Currently enter key doesn't work (I don't know why) but I must invoke a method on a given object when enter key is pressed WITHOUT also going by form's onsubmit attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$$('input[type!=button],select', '#formid')
```

`*` selects all elements.

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of

```
$$('#formId input[type!=button],#formId select')
```

Haven't been using prototype but i assume most CSS selectors work